# Inserting into multiple databases from form submit

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

- I have two database tables, `posts` and `post_tags`.
- I have a form that has a dropdown where the user can select multiple tags.
- How would I insert everything except the tags into the `posts` table and just the tags into the `post_tags` table?

`posts` table:

```
+----+----------+---------+
| id | username | message |
+----+----------+---------+
```

`post_tags` table:

```
+----+---------+-----+
| id | post_id | tag |
+----+---------+-----+
```

If the user has select multiple tags from the dropdown list, it should insert each one into the table in its own individual row, i.e.:

```
+----+---------+-------+
| id | post_id |  tag  |
+----+---------+-------+
|  1 |       1 | hello |
|  2 |       1 | world |
+----+---------+-------+
```

I have inserting *just* the post information done, but I'm not sure how to insert the tags into the second table.

My `Post` model class:

```
class Post extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'post';      
}
```

Part of my `PostController` class to submit *just* the post information:

```
$server = new Server;
$server->name = Input::get('name');
$server->ip_address = Input::get('ip_address');
$server->port = Input::get('port');
$server->info = Input::get('info');
$server->website = Input::get('website');
$server->country = Input::get('country');
$server->save();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can save posts and post_tags separately in `PostController`

```
$post = new Post;
$post->postData = Input::get('postData');
$post->save();

$post_tags = new Post_tags;
$post_tags->tags = Input::get('tags');
$post_tags->save();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What would the `Post_tags` model look like? What would the relationship look like in both models?